# Maximizing Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

In Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, there is a question on Chapter $1$ which goes as follows:

> Let $S(n,k)$ denote a Stirling number of the kind (ie, $S(n,k)$ is the
>   number of ways to distribute $n$ elements over $k$ non-empty
>   subsets). For each $n$, define $K_n \in \mathbb N$ and $t_n \in \mathbb R$ by
>
> $$S(n,K_n) \geq S(n,k)$$
>
> for all $k \in \mathbb N$ and
>
> $$\frac{(t_n+2)t_n\log(t_n+2)}{t_n+1} = n$$
>
> Show that for all sufficiently large $n$, either $K_n= \lfloor t_n \rfloor$ or $K_n= \lfloor t_n \rfloor + 1$.

I admit that I've been truly at loss on where to start with. I can't seem to relate $t_n$'s equation to $S(n,k)$'s definition or its properties (recurrence relation, closed form expression, etc).

All help is appreciated!

EDIT: Just clarifying that $\lfloor t_n\rfloor$ is the floor function, which returns the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $t_n$.